# What is the version of Docker to install, the 5 series or the 18 series?

Tags: docker

This is my first attempt on using Docker. I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to install Docker on an Ubuntu instance.

When I reached the `apt-cache madison docker-ce` step, it showed many versions, a series of version 5.19.xx and another series of version 18.06.xx. Partial output:

```
docker-ce | 5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
docker-ce | 5:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
...
docker-ce | 5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
docker-ce | 18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
docker-ce | 18.06.2~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
...
```

Should I be installing version 5 or 18?

Comment: IMHO you should use the [convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script), which will install the latest docker-ce, e.g. Docker version 19.03.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) shows the same output. I don't know why. But if you want to install docker, normaly you install the latest version for your ubuntu dist:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was installing nvidia-container-runtime after installing docker. It needs docker-ce >= 5.19 so I have to install it from the list obtained from the command by this

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

Choosing the specific version from the list obtained.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
```

Finally

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Now my nvidia-containerFor my specific requirement.

```
sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi
```